# Git hook that prevents branch from ever being up-to-date

Tags: git, githooks

I'm writing a git based deployment solution, which supports multiple users and multiple repos.  I would prefer it if, every time a user pushes a ref, the update hook would be called, regardless of whether the remote version is up to date.

The rationale is that deployments can often fail for reasons outside of the code, and I would rather users not have to modify a file in order to retry a deployment.

How can I ensure that the ref is never up-to-date, and an update hook is always called.

I should add that simply failing (non-zero return) the update after deploying isn't desirable, since that causes the client to receive a non-zero error code, and the objects that were sent would need to be resent (i.e. nothing gets cached)

Comment: I think you should just provide a *“redeploy”* service you can start by, for example, pressing a big red button in your office. In any way, having deployment fail for reasons outside of code sounds like a very odd thing, and you should probably work on fixing that to ensure determinism in your environment.

Comment: Hah, I like that idea.  I guess I forgot to mention that these are user facing git repos, so I'd have to setup a button for every one of my customers.  Which would actually be pretty awesome if it were feasible, lol.